# Absurd variable update in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am a beginner in python.

I am writing a simple script to calculate the solution for a system of linear equations (Ax= b) using the Cramer's rule . I declared a coefficient matrix (A) and a constant matrix (b) as numpy arrays and initialised a loop that generates the three matrices after column substitution of the original coefficient matrix.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,7,9]])
b = np.array([1,1,1])

var_holder= {}

for i in range(0,3):
    print(A)
    A_changed = np.transpose(A)
    A_changed[i] = b
    var_holder['A_' + str (i+1)] =   np.transpose(A_changed)
    del(A_changed)
    

locals().update(var_holder)
print(A_1)
print(A_2)
print(A_3)
```

The output for this seems to three identity matrices with A getting updated at each iteration step. This is not what we want.

However, if I declare A inside the loop, it solves the issue:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([1,1,1])

var_holder= {}

for i in range(0,3):
    A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,7,9]])
    print(A)
    A_changed = np.transpose(A)
    A_changed[i] = b
    var_holder['A_' + str (i+1)] =   np.transpose(A_changed)
    del(A_changed)
    

locals().update(var_holder)
print(A_1)
print(A_2)
print(A_3)
```

I am not sure what is causing the variable A to get updated at each iteration step. Kindly help me understand the issue for better clarity. TIA!

Comment: You're not declaring `A`.  You're assigning to it.  When you assign to it in the loop, you're creating a new array each time through the loop.  When the assignment is outside the loop, it reuses the same array each time through.

Comment: `np.transpose()` returns a view into the original array. So modifying the view modifies the original array.